# Installing Ubuntu mini without ethernet

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-minimal

I usually install Ubuntu mini on my laptop and then customize it. However, unlike previous times, I do not have access to an Ethernet connection this time around, only WiFi.
Is there a way to work around this? I found many posts asking similar questions but I couldn't find an straightforward answer of how to resolve it.

Thanks,
Tohiko

Comment: I believe it will work via WiFi, won't it?

Comment: Only a few WiFi devices are natively support in a standard desktop installation media. Fewer, if any at all, will have support in the mini iso so... I think you got the picture.

Comment: I understand of course that it won't make the iso "minimal". But is there a way to support the particular WiFi device that I have on my machine in a "minimal"-like ISO.

Comment: Why do you go for Ubuntu Mini?

Comment: I like a minimalist system where I know all the dependencies that are being installed

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact problem, trying to install ubuntu mini but they dont include wifi module in their mini iso. I have the following solution

**1) Use a live ubuntu desktop iso to boot**
dd a normal desktop ubuntu iso to a usb
boot the computer with that live usb

```
sudo cfdisk /dev/sda
sudo mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sda1
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda2
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda3

cd /tmp && wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/debootstrap/debootstrap_1.0.114ubuntu1_all.deb
cd /tmp && dpkg -i debootstrap*.deb

sudo mkdir -p /mnt/usb
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/usb
sudo mkdir /mnt/usb/boot
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb/boot
sudo debootstrap bionic /mnt/usb http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/usb/dev
sudo mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/usb/dev/pts
sudo mount -t sysfs /sys /mnt/usb/sys
sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/usb/proc

sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /mnt/usb/etc/apt/
sudo chroot /mnt/usb apt-get update


sudo chroot /mnt/usb apt-get -y install grub-efi-amd64 sudo make git ssh linux-firmware linux-image-generic nano intel-microcode curl software-properties-common unzip network-manager net-tools wpasupplicant
sudo chroot /mnt/usb apt-get -y install alsa-utils pulseaudio 

# add your packages here, Install your driver here
# sudo chroot /mnt/usb apt-get -y install papirus-icon-theme cpanminus gexec libcpan-distnameinfo-perl libcpan-meta-check-perl libfile-pushd-perl liblocal-lib-p$
# sudo chroot /mnt/usb apt-get -y install xorg openbox obconf lxterminal conky tint2 feh pcmanfm xarchiver chromium-browser gmrun 
# sudo chroot /mnt/usb apt-get -y install viewnior ttf-wqy-microhei 
# sudo chroot /mnt/usb apt-get -y install transmission-gtk rar unrar zip evince scrot 

sudo chroot /mnt/usb passwd

sudo echo -e "/dev/sda1  /boot       vfat    umask=0077      0       1" | sudo tee -a /mnt/usb/etc/fstab
sudo echo -e "/dev/sda2 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1"  | sudo tee -a /mnt/usb/etc/fstab
sudo echo -e "/dev/sda3 /home               ext4    defaults        0       2"  | sudo tee -a /mnt/usb/etc/fstab



sudo chroot /mnt/usb
# Following in chroot environment
apt-get install grub-efi-amd64
grub-mkdevicemap
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
update-grub
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi  --bootloader-id=grub_uefi --efi-directory=/boot

sudo shutdown -r now
```

To get online

```
sudo nmtui
```

This is sort of like how you install arch. You can use arch wiki as a references

**2) Use debian mini so with firmware**
https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/
But of course this will install debian instead.